# How to retrieve line number of next delimiter appearance?

Tags: shell

Please observe the scenario below:

file1.txt

Here Numbers are line numbers

```
1 abc
2 def
3 [hi]
4 afg
5 jik
6 [jim]
7 jum
8 [hey]
```

in this file how to retrieve line number(6th in case) that is from 3rd record to immediately next '[' appearance?

I have used `sed -n 'n,$p' file1.txt|grep -n '\['` (n-line number) but this is not working as much i expected,please help in this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is it not working as expected? It's kind of hard to understand from the text. Please show the literal output that you want.

Comment: What is the expected output exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with awk then `awk '($2 ~ /\[/)&&($1 > line_no) {print $1; exit;}' file.txt`
where `line_no` is the line number after which you want to find `[`

```
$ awk '($2 ~ /\[/)&&($1 > 3) {print $1; exit;}' file.txt
6
$ awk '($2 ~ /\[/)&&($1 > 4) {print $1; exit;}' file.txt
6
$ awk '($2 ~ /\[/)&&($1 > 6) {print $1; exit;}' file.txt
8
```